# CodeIgniter Session out page display issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, session-timeout

[image]

I am developing one web site where i used Codeigniter.In that i used Session time out.aftet session time out if i clicked on any button or any window then my login screen appears in that window or div.
eg.
if i clicked on my notification box then it appears in that div also,how should i proceed.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

i am able handle session at time of page loading but if session expired after some time from page loaded time then above error occurs then how to trigger session expire event

Comment: Hopes help you: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/126668

Answer (score 1):

At the starting of the page..check if the session variable is set. If it is not set, then redirect the page to the login page.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['variable'])
{
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

The session will automatically expire after the defined time in the config file.Hope this helps :)

Comment: i know how to handle session at time of page loading but if session expired after some time from page loaded time then above error occurs then how to trigger session expire event

Answer (score 0):

At the time of login set a varibale to true and after click or in the constructer of controller check the value of that varibale.

```
public Function login()
{
   $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn',TRUE);
}
```

and now check in controller

```
function __construct()
{ 
parent::__construct();
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) 
   {
    redirect('');//if NOT then redirect to home page
   }
}
```

}